# does a tag on azure resource group gets applied to resources inside the resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-group

I have a query on azure resource tagging. I have a resource group with some resources inside it. If I apply a tag on the resource group, does the same tag get applied to the resources inside that resource group? Or do I need to apply tag on each resources inside the resource group individually even though the tag needed is same?

If tag on resource group get applied automatically to the resources inside the group, then when the tag on the resource group should be applied i.e. whether before the resources are assigned to the group or after the resources are applied to the group.

Though I could not find any similar question but yet if any is there then please point me to the same.

Comment: The answer is no, do you want all resources in a resource group use the same tag? If is, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-policy-tags)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you could find this out in under 5 minutes in the portal, but since you asked - no, tags do not propagate.

Comment: To apply resource group tag to its resources you could write a script to check for new untagged resources and tag them accordingly. Then you could schedule such script in Azure Automation.

Answer (score 1):

In general answer is No but you can specify policy to do so.
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-resources?tabs=json#inherit-tags) is azure documentation link explaining it in detail.